# What is the role of django REST framework if I want to integrate angularjs with django?

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to set up django with angularjs and play around with it. Most of the tutorials contain something about django REST framework, Creating endpoints for an application, APIs and so forth. What is django REST framework, what are endpoints, APIs, why are they important for angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should learn what is angularJS and how it works, with that knowledge is pretty clear why there is need for an API.

In short words: You feed angularJS with template and data, AngularJS will take it and build correct site on client side. There won't be any benefits if you won't change data dynamically. That's why you need to have API for you app (to exchange data, not pre-build templates) and for that API, good choice is Django Rest Framework.